# How return two equal max values for the same country when the query is grouped by the country?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example I have to write a query that shows the customer who had spent the most in each country but if a country has two customers with same max value i have to show them both in the output.

I have wrote the query that return the maximum value for each customer in each country but the last country in my example which is 'United Kingdom' has two customers with same maximum values and i couldn't show them both.

```
SELECT c1.CustomerId, c1.FirstName,c1.LastName,c1.Country, 
       MAX(c1.TotalSpent) as TotalSpent
FROM
    (SELECT c.CustomerId,c.FirstName, c.LastName,i.BillingCountry 
            Country, SUM(i.Total) totalspent
     FROM Customer c
     JOIN Invoice i
     ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
     GROUP BY 1
     ORDER BY totalspent
    ) c1
GROUP BY 4
ORDER BY Country
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.BillingCountry as Country,
             SUM(i.Total) as totalspent,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.BillingCountry ORDER BY SUM(i.Total) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Customer c JOIN
           Invoice i
           ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
      GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.BillingCountry
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY Country;
```

This also fixes your `GROUP BY` clauses so they are consistent with the columns being selected.